# Javascript For Toggling Password And Text Type Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I am Trying javascript to toggle the input type="password" and "text" To Show Password Or Hide Password. But It works perfect for One Field. But Not working for 3 Fields.

When User checks 'show password' option, it gets sets as type="text" and user can see password instead of Dots.. BUT When user uncheck show password option, It is not getting set type="password"

Code is As Follows:

In Head Section -->>

```
<script>
function changeType()
{
    document.form_signup_info.old_password.type=(document.form_signup_info.option.value=(document.form_signup_info.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
function changeType1()
{
    document.form_signup_info.new_password.type=(document.form_signup_info.option.value=(document.form_signup_info.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
function changeType2()
{
    document.form_signup_info.cpassword.type=(document.form_signup_info.option.value=(document.form_signup_info.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
</script>
```

And In Body Section -->>

```
<label>Old Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" placeholder="Old Password*">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value='-1' onchange="changeType()" />Show Old Password</label>


<label>New Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password*">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value='-1' onchange="changeType1()" />Show New Password</label>


<label>Confirm New Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm New Password*">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value='-1' onchange="changeType2()" />Show Confirm Password</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set Different option for each field And It worked perfectly. My New Code is As Follows..

```
 <script>
 function changeType()
 {
    document.form_signup_info.old_password.type=(document.form_signup_info.option.value=(document.form_signup_info.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
function changeType1()
{
document.form_signup_info.new_password.type=(document.form_signup_info.option1.value= (document.form_signup_info.option1.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
function changeType2()
{
document.form_signup_info.cpassword.type=(document.form_signup_info.option2.value=(document.form_signup_info.option2.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
}
</script>



 <label>Old Password :</label>
 <input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" placeholder="Old Password*">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value='-1' onchange="changeType()" />Show Old Password</label>


 <label>New Password :</label>
 <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password*">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value='-1' onchange="changeType1()" />Show New Password</label>


 <label>Confirm New Password :</label>
 <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm New Password*">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value='-1' onchange="changeType2()" />Show Confirm Password</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `type` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('old_password').type = "text";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/SGgAk/)

Or use the `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById('old_password').setAttribute('type', 'text');
```